# Python C API: How to store any Python Object as a void* without knowing its type?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I was wondering if it is possible to store **any Python object** as a void* in Python C API which will be returned later to python as-is.

I tried to do something like this:

```c
store_python_object(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int retval;
    PyObject *self_capsule;
    void *stored_object;
    /* Parse input arguments */
    retval = PyArg_ParseTuple(args,
                              "OO:store_python_object",
                              &self_capsule,
                              &stored_object);
    if (!retval) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // More code here...
    // Return stored_object to python as-is
}
```

But this seems to have a weird behavior when storing an int for example (Again, I want to store any Python object, not only int).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "weird behavior"? Does it segmentation fault or something?

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do? Can't you use the correct pointer format then 
 (if absolutely necessary) convert it to `void*`?

Comment: Hi @user202729. I am trying to store an object given by the user (python) and not touch it (just store), and then later on return it to Python as-is. When the python passes a string it works well (the returned object looks fine), when the Python passes f-string I get segmentation fault, when I pass an int the returned number is (num+2) which I think suggests memory error.

Comment: @user202729 what do you mean by "correct pointer format"? I want to be able to get any python object (int, float, list, custom class instance), store it, and then return it as-is.

Comment: I don't really see why this isn't working. Possibly you should get a `PyObject*` from `PyArg_ParseTuple`, then convert to `void*` though (not 100% sure what the C rules are...). But this really needs an [mre] - there's all kind of mistakes that could be hiding in `// More code here...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my problem:
**I stored a python-object in C  without increasing its reference counter** (using `Py_INCREF(PyObject *o)`). So apparently the python deallocated the python-object which caused the weird behavior.

Thanks for everyone.